# Reading a two column data file and writing first element of first column in bashscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a data file, say input.dat:

```
 0.00000     -21.9934807 
 0.00349     -21.9953289
 0.00697     -22.0007229
 0.01046     -22.0094204
 0.01395     -22.0210171
 0.01743     -22.0350628
 0.02092     -22.0510826
 0.02441     -22.0685902
 0.02789     -22.0871773
 0.03138     -22.1064396
 0.03487     -22.1260700
 0.03836     -22.1457787
 0.04184     -22.1653156
 0.04533     -22.1844902
 0.04882     -22.2031174
 0.05230     -22.2210617
 0.05579     -22.2381897
 0.05928     -22.2543869
 0.06276     -22.2695751
 0.06625     -22.2836666
 0.06974     -22.2965908
 0.07322     -22.3082924
 0.07671     -22.3187332
 0.08020     -22.3278618
 0.08368     -22.3356419
 0.08717     -22.3420353
 0.09066     -22.3470383
 0.09414     -22.3506260
 0.09763     -22.3527832
 0.10112     -22.3535042
```

I want to read the file in bash script and write only 10th line, 1st column data (0.03138). similarly, the 20th line, 1st column data should be written. Can one help me exactly what code should I write in the script. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain which code you have tried. Take a look at Documentation in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/3947/row-manipulation/28060/extract-specific-column-field-from-specific-line#t=201704180908587581529)

Answer (score 2):

Text manipulation is usually done with awk, not pure bash. Here is how you would do it:

```
awk 'NR==10 || NR==20 { print $1 }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with `sed`.

Take only lines 10 and 20:

```
sed -n -e 10p -e 20p input.dat
```

Extract only first column:

```
sed -n -e 10p -e 20p input.dat | sed -e 's/ .*//'
```

In case of every line starts by a space (as I faced when copying your input.dat content), you may remove it with `sed -e 's/^ //'`, so:

```
sed -n -e 10p -e 20p input.dat | sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ .*//'
```

Comment: Thanks again. I have another question. Is is possible to write the lines generated by above script into a data file with command within the script. For example, if I write,                                                                                        sed -n -e 10p -e 20p input.dat | sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ .*//'  > dataset.dat                               For me it is not working. Can you suggest me someting regarding this. Many thanks.

Comment: @Leostorm10 `sed -n -e 10p -e 20p input.dat | sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ .*//' > dataset.dat` works fine in my system.

Comment: Ok. I have now got it with entire command.                                                However, if I want separately like,                                                            sed -n -e 10p input.dat | sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ .*//' > dataset.dat                   sed  -n -e 20p input.dat | sed -e 's/^ //' -e 's/ .*//' > dataset.dat                                                It is not writing two numbers  in dataset.dat

Comment: @Leostorm10 Because ">" doesn't append the content but writes it removing the previous content. If you want to append content to the end of the file you must use ">>" operator.